# Where can i find information about whats going behind the scene when creating thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Where can i find information about whats going on behind the scene when Im creating a new 
thread ?

when i write

```
    Thread t = new Thread ()
....
t.start()....
```

i want to know what actually is going on...
can you please redirect me ?

Comment: What platform? .Net, Mono/Linux, Mono/OSX?

Comment: sorry ....net ( i added)

Comment: Please do not this ever.You can use ILDASM/Monodis to disassemble every .NET assembly.I used Monodis a few times just to see what happens behind some stuff,but I've never cracked an app,so please do not that except for learning.Also,Monodis also dissambles stuff much better than ILDASM and allows c# instead of just IL.Happy learning,and remember not to use it in evil ways(well more evil than this).

Comment: He doesn't say he want to see the actual (dissassambled) code, just what goes on behind the scenes in general probably. Someone downvoted it, but I don't see a reason. Understanding the behind-the-scenes is very valuable, though just researching native threads will work as well.

Comment: A good place to learn about what's going on under the hood is Joe Duffy's book, *Concurrent Programming on Windows*. That will answer your questions about what happens when you start a thread ... and a whole lot more. Well worth the price.

Comment: Also, see [CLR via C#](http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-C-Jeffrey-Richter/dp/0735627045). This isn't something you're going to learn via a [so] question.

Comment: @jom thanks. please convert you r commet to answer so i can choose......p.s. Thank you also Dykam.

Comment: @John Saunders   : i asked for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although managed threads don't necessarily behave the same way as native threads, have a look at this article which covers the basic premise:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681917(v=vs.85).aspx

Specifically, when you create a thread the code will be running in the context below:

A thread is the entity within a process that can be scheduled for execution. All threads of a process share its virtual address space and system resources. In addition, each thread maintains exception handlers, a scheduling priority, thread local storage, a unique thread identifier, and a set of structures the system will use to save the thread context until it is scheduled. The thread context includes the thread's set of machine registers, the kernel stack, a thread environment block, and a user stack in the address space of the thread's process. Threads can also have their own security context, which can be used for impersonating clients.

Answer (score 1):

Just so it's here as an answer, [Jeffrey Richter's CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) will probably† teach you stuff you don't know about CLR internals.

And here's [Joe Duffy's Concurrent Programming on Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X)

† in a statistical sense